# Printing variable in nasm using system call

Tags: variables, nasm

I have been trying to print a variable from the `.bss` section but no output is coming. Thanks for the help in advance.

```
section .text
global main
main:
mov al,10 ; 10 to be displayed
mov [num], al
mov edx,1
mov ecx,[num]
mov ebx,1
mov eax,4  ; calling sys_out
int 0x80

mov eax,1 ;calling sys_exit 
int 0x80

section .bss
num resb 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `mov ecx,num` (or `lea ecx,[num]`).

Comment: That wouldn't really solve the problem, since there's no syscall for printing integers. The integer 10 would have to be converted into the string "10" first.

Comment: I thought the intention was to output a new line character. If the question was about converting 8-bit integers to strings I completely misunderstood it. Sorry.